# "Glancing to heaven" in Andrew's Brain by E. L. Doctorow

Tags: meaning, andrews-brain, e-l-doctorow

In Andrew's Brain by E. L. Doctorow:

> Naturally the rug was rolled up and Bill and Betty did one of their
> vaudeville routines, the old soft shoe, a George M. Cohan number, “…
> for it was Mary, Mary, plain as any name can be …” And with such grace
> and ease, laughing as they accomplished this or that move, Bill at one
> point essaying some kind of double time step and **Betty glancing to
> heaven**. One of their friends had hoisted himself up onto the piano
> bench to accompany them and sing the lyrics in his mute tenor, and it
> was so fine.

What does he mean by "**glancing to heaven**"? Is it a kind of dance move? or does it mean that she was looking at the ceiling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a dance move - as you suspect, it just indicated that Betty is looking upwards at the ceiling.

However, it's worth taking a moment to unpack the choice of phrase here. Looking at "heaven" is a not uncommon euphemism for looking at the open sky but it's an odd pick for looking at a ceiling. The intent, it seems, is to communicate the pleasure that Betty is feeling at dancing - she is at "ease", it is "so fine", she is "laughing" - clearly having a good time. So using "heaven" to communicate looking upwards helps reinforce that sense of joy.